# Упрощение стилей

Tags: scss, sass, material-ui, стилизация

Имеются элементы такого вида:

```
 <Typography
    className={styles.element}
    sx={{ color: `${getColor(status)}` }}>
                {state}
</Typography>
```

Возможно ли упростить данную конструкцию?
В проекте используется scss, material, clsx(только ввели, им я ещё не особо пользовался)

Comment: Зачем? Я бы так-же написал... Можно вывести sx в переменную и поставить ссылку, но это тупо.

Comment: Ревью не нравится использование и sx и className...

Comment: походу да... Ревьюшникам лишь-бы переменных натыкать даже там где не нужно! =)))))))))))))))))))